# Render ASP.NET MVC Spark view to string, fails grandchildren views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 with the Spark view engine.  I have a view that renders correctly when ASP.NET itself renders it, but when I perform an ajax call to re-render a partial view to a string so that I can replace the html with jQuery, it renders the partial view, its children, but not its grandchildren views.

The view hierarchy is Index-> Parent Partial View -> Child Partial View -> Grandchild Partial View.

The code below is being used to render the Parent Partial View to a string:

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);

            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

When it renders, the Parent Partial View and all Child Partial Views render properly, but none of the Grandchild Partial Views render.  What should be happening to correctly render all children and grandchildren with the partial view into a string?

Comment: Would you be able to post how your views are calling each other? Are you using Html.RenderPartial or are yo using the build in Spark Partials? It does make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

The above code actually does work.  The error was elsewhere in the javascript code that used the output.

So, if you need to render a view to a string, the above code should work.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know Mark, I was worried since I thought it should work, and does in my environments, so I wanted to see how you were calling the views. Cheers,