# Get the generated html file inside an action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC Controller which provides a simple View

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ZipIndex() {
        // Get the file returned bu Index() and zip it 
        return File(/* zip stream */);
    }
}
```

As you can see from above what I need to implement is a method that gets the html generated by Index(), zip it and return it as a file that can be downloaded.

I know how to zip, but I don't know how to get the html.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936809/render-asp-net-mvc-spark-view-to-string-fails-grandchildren-views?rq=1 - may be the answer.

Comment: If the user needs the HTML content of a page can't they just right-click and *save as*?

Comment: @RichardEverett I'd be surprised if many users actually know about being able to save source of the page (and have convenient way of doing so - i.e. on phones). Note that result may not be HTML (i.e. CSV) - so having an easy way for both view and download zip of the same view look very reasonably use case for me.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. Thanks a lot. That works. I wonder if there is a way by calling the Index() method directly? That method that you linked to requires the model as an argument. I have a lot of code in Index() to set up the view and wouldn't want to duplicate it in ZipIndex().

Comment: @RichardEverett. In my case even if the user knew to right click it wouldn't work because the page contains video. I include the video in the zip file.

Comment: So you want not only the HTML output from the action method, but also the contents of all links within the HTML?

Comment: @RichardEverett. Yes, you can say that. But I am not asking for a method how to do that. I already know how to get the content.

Comment: @IlirDeda I have expanded the reply below to show a solution that uses View rendering and .NET 4.5 zip techniques.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this post out http://approache.com/blog/render-any-aspnet-mvc-actionresult-to/. It gives a neat way to render the output of any ActionResult to a string.

**Edit**

Building on the technique outlined in the above article, a complete solution could look like this

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Web;

public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public FileContentResult ZipIndex()
    {
        // Render the View output: 
        var viewString = View("TheViewToRender").Capture(ControllerContext);
        // Create a zip file containing the resulting markup
        using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StringReader(viewString);
            using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(outputStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry entry = zip.CreateEntry("MyView.html", CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    sr.BaseStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                }
            }
            return File(outputStream.ToArray(), MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip, "Filename.zip");
        }
    }
}

public static class ActionResultExtensions {
    public static string Capture(this ActionResult result, ControllerContext controllerContext) {
        using (var it = new ResponseCapture(controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response)) {
            result.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
            return it.ToString();
        }
    }
}
public class ResponseCapture : IDisposable {
    private readonly HttpResponseBase response;
    private readonly TextWriter originalWriter;
    private StringWriter localWriter;
    public ResponseCapture(HttpResponseBase response) {
        this.response = response;
        originalWriter = response.Output;
        localWriter = new StringWriter();
        response.Output = localWriter;
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        localWriter.Flush();
        return localWriter.ToString();
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        if (localWriter != null) {
            localWriter.Dispose();
            localWriter = null;
            response.Output = originalWriter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only seems to work if there is now Model being used.  When I used a model it failed to populate it.